# Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.AdapterWithErrorHandler' to type 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter'

Tags: c#, azure, oauth-2.0, botframework

When working with SSO Microsoft-Teams-Samples:

\Microsoft-Teams-Samples\samples\bot-conversation-sso-quickstart\csharp_dotnetcore\BotConversationSsoQuickstart\BotConversationSsoQuickstart.csproj

[image]

It works correctly to get the token, however when you write "logout" in the message, it fails returning the following message:

**Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.AdapterWithErrorHandler' to type 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter'.**

[image]

Is it a bug in the code sample? What will be the expected behaviour for 'logout' action? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Sample source referenced: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/blob/main/samples/bot-conversation-sso-quickstart/csharp_dotnetcore/BotConversationSsoQuickstart/Dialogs/LogoutDialog.cs

The example uses a `IBotFrameworkAdapter`, but that has now been termed `Obsolete` which is a good indicator that the example is out of date. Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.botframeworkadapter?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable

You can also see this is if you go the source of `AdapterWithErrorHandler`, which inherits from `CloudAdapter` ( https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/80.skills-simple-bot-to-bot/SimpleRootBot/AdapterWithErrorHandler.cs )

Simply change your setup to instantiate a `CloudAdapter` and it should work. Docs of `CloudAdapter`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.integration.aspnet.core.cloudadapter?view=botbuilder-dotnet-stable